# How would one go about debugging a system that extensively uses the Observer pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

In trying to better understand the Observer pattern, what are some of its properties and in a system that predominately uses the Observer method how would one go about debugging large sections of code in such a system?

Answer (score 1):

Using the observer pattern, the subject (or a helper class) usually has a list of observers. When an event fires, it loops through the list and calls a method in those observers to tell them about the event.
So this is perfectly debuggable. If these observers are classes in your program too, you can just follow the loop and step into each of the event handlers.

If you observer is an external object (COM) or a precombiled object (obj file), you can't do that, but there are not other ways to inspect that code as well, so this 'problem' is a more general problem and not specific to the observer pattern.

Comment: interesting point. So how would we then ensure that the subjects are updating states correctly, observers are recording the updates correctly, and then check if the communication(update) protocol between the two is working correctly?

Comment: Well, it is hard to put this in a general rule, because how code can be tested depends on the way it is developed. At a certain point the state is displayed. That process can only be checked visually, by manual testing. But the communication below can also be put in unit tests. You can make a test observer to check if the subject passes the right state after your test triggers some events. And you can create a test subject that fires fixed states to see if the observer handles them right.

Comment: Testing this also depends on the protocol. You can have a simple event which is little more than a call to a procedure, probably within the same application even, or you can have an observer on the other end of the world that is listening through a TCP connection. In that last case, you will probably have a local object too that propagates the information to a TCP connection while the subject itself just raises local events. But still, the observer pattern isn't that complex basically. How you should debug and test it relies more on the implementation than on the pattern itself.